# Как сделать так, чтобы Navbar появлялся на всех страницах (без копирования кода) (PHP не подойдёт) Django HTML

Tags: html, django, bootstrap5

Я хочу, чтобы `Navbar` был на всех страницах и тот код который снизу был в другом файле (Обязательно в папке '`static`'). `PHP` не подойдёт т.к. `django` не обрабатывает `PHP`.

Если что я использую `Bootstrap 5`.

Можно в принципе с `{% extends %}` но я не понимаю как туда передать путь к '`static`' папке

Код для `Navbar`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
              <img src="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' %}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
              <span style="color: white">Company</span>
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
              
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Services
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/subscriptions">Subscriptions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте доки по шаблонам джанго. Там это весьма неплохо расписано. Вам надо написать базовый шаблон, и остальные шаблоны как расширяющие его.
к примеру:

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
<!-- ваша навигашка -->
</nav>
<div class="site-container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %} <!-- сюда будет вставляться содержимое расширяющих шаблонов -->
</div>
```

about.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title%}Ебаут{% endblock %}
{% block content%}о нас{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title%}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content%}
блаблабла здрасьти на сайте<br/>
Новости сайта:<br/>
    {% include 'main/news.html' %}
    <a href="{% url 'news' %}">Архив новостей...</a>

{% endblock %}
```